# Provisional Headers are shown - GET requests

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an issue with my ionic mobile app
When I build my project on browser my requests correctly send every headers and authentification works. But if I’m on my android device, I don’t have any headers and I have “Provisional Headers are shown” on my chrome debugger.

[debugger chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydAku.png)

I’m using HttpClient angular.
Do any of you have any idea ?
Thanks in advance ! :)

My ionic info: 
[ionic info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSYBg.png)

EDIT 1 :
My authent request look like this: 
`https://URL/url-login-api?login='+username+'&password='+password`

Here is my http service for GET method:

```html
public get(pageName, action, params2): Promise<any> {
      let headers = new HttpHeaders();
      let httpParams = new HttpParams();
      for (const item in params2) {
        httpParams = httpParams.append(item, params2[item]);
      }
      return this.http.request(
          'GET',
          this.host + HTTP_CONFIG[pageName][action].URL,
          {
              headers: headers,
              params: httpParams,
              withCredentials: !HTTP_CONFIG[pageName]  [action].PARAMS.withCredentials ? false : true
          }
          ).toPromise().then((resp) => {
           console.log("Response: ", resp)
           return (resp);
          });
     }
```

And here is how I call my http service for authentification:

```html
this.httpServices.get("AUTH", "LOGIN", {login , password}).then((resp) => {
     const res = resp;
     this.events.publish("logged_in");
     const cookie = JSON.parse(res);
     let token;
     const ln = cookie.length;
     for (let i = 0; i < ln ; i++) {
        if (cookie[i].Key === ".DOTNETNUKE") {
          token = cookie[i].Value;
        }
      }
}
```

Here is the backend authentification method, they gave me (I don't really have any access on it yet). The exact same method is working in browser mode (With Set-Cookie header sent etc...) :

```html
if (loginStatus != UserLoginStatus.LOGIN_USERNOTAPPROVED &&
                    loginStatus != UserLoginStatus.LOGIN_FAILURE)
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("content-type", "application/javascript");
                    var coll = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                    foreach (string cookie in HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies)
                    {
                        var httpCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookie];
                        if (httpCookie != null)
                            coll.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(cookie,
                                string.Join(",", httpCookie.Value)));
                    }
                    return Json.Serialize(coll);
                }
```

Comment: HI Joris, I think it would be good if you share a few more details about your authentication methods, maybe even some code if helpfull.

Comment: Hello @Andreas thanks for your response. I updated my post with more informations about my authentification method.
It's quite an old application I have to make it work again. I don't really have access to backend either...